# What is the reason behind a class holding a pointer to its instance as a private member?

Tags: c++, class, reference, static, private

I don't know if this concept has a name. I have a class declaration;

```
class A
{
    public:
      ...
    private:
      static A* me;
}
```

- Is this a pattern?
- Why would anyone do that?

Comment: Failing more code, possibly a singleton (search "Singleton pattern")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Failing more code to diagnose the intent, it looks a lot like an implementation of the *Singleton pattern*.

There is a lot of reference material available here on stackoverflow and on wikipedia;

- https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Singleton_pattern
- [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1008019/3747990)

You will find there is probably some implementation of a "get instance" method or a friend factory method.

```
class A {
public:
    static A* getInstance();
// or
    friend A* getInstance();

private:
    static A* me;
};
```

Why is it done? To quote wikipedia

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that **restricts the instantiation of a class to one object**.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before in `Singletons`.

A singleton is an object that can only exist once in memory. To achieve this you 'hide' its Constructor and expose it's instance my means of an accessor (like `getInstance()` to a private static instance of the object. This is why it keeps a private pointer to itself.

The idea is that every time some calls `getInstance()` you return the pointer to the static instance. This way you ensure there is only one instance for the Class.

A tutorial on Singleton's can be found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/120392-singleton-design/)

Answer (score 1):

Alone it has no significant meaning. However if coupled with a `static A& getInstance()` function it seems more like Singleton pattern.

Singleton pattern is basically a way to create only 1 instance of this class that is used everywhere in the program.

I prefer another way of implementing this pattern though. There is no particular reason to use this way of implementation other than personal preference.

```
class A{
private:
    class A(){}                  //To make sure it can only be constructed inside the class.
    class A(const A&) = delete;
    class A(A&&) = delete;      //To make sure that it cannot be moved or copied
public:
    static A& getInstance(){
        static A inst;             //That's the only place the constructor is called.
        return inst;
    }
};
```

Hope that helped.